# Why wont this query work

Tags: sql, sql-server, openquery

I have the following SQL openquery

```
SELECT      @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(RMSPROD2,''SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT W.Bond) AS NoBID_Count
                                                FROM TIB.WRMAST w
                                                WHERE (w.BID In (''No Bid'', ''No Cost'', ''None'') AND w.CtlNumber = ''''' + @WarControlID + ''''''')'
```

When I run this query I get the following error:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(RMSPROD2,'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT W.Bond) AS NoBond_Count
                                                FROM TIBURON.WRMAST w
                                                WHERE (w.Bond In ('No Bond', 'No Bail', 'None') AND w.CtlNumber = ''575403''')
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'No'.
```

What is the error that is being thrown I have no indications in the design window of any issues

Comment: Why are you building text strings for your query? Why not just run it?

Comment: I see that the error message with the Print@TSQL shows a different WHERE clause however that was a error on my part when posting the question.  Cut and paste without an edit.

Comment: The you should update the question with the actual code and error.

Comment: I am running the query against an oracle linked server and the OpenQUERY will not allow a variable

Comment: I would love to update the question if I knew how to make that happen

Comment: @Perry Why did you tag this post with "sql-server" then?

Comment: I _think_ he is running the query from SQL-server and connecting to an Oracle DB. So he has to use SQL-server string rules to form the text to send to Oracle.

Comment: That is correct I am running this on a SQL server 2014 linked to an Oracle Server

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of your problem is that you are inadvertently closing the opening quote here :

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(RMSPROD2,'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT W.Bond) AS NoBond_Count
                                                FROM TIBURON.WRMAST w
                                                WHERE (w.Bond In ('
```

Hence you are getting the error near No. In java for instance, \ is the escape character, and so to ensure continuity, we would have to write :

```
"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT W.Bond) AS NoBond_Count
                                                    FROM TIBURON.WRMAST w
                                                    WHERE (w.Bond In (\'     "  //till the end
```

Search for appropriate escape character in the language of your choice and apply it.

Comment: @FernandoGutierrez, my answer has been java formatted. In java, you can write {String SQL="Select dummy from dual"}. If you type select dummy from dual in Oracle, you will see column name returned as DUMMY, all Upper case. If you want to ensure case sensitivity, you have to write select "Dummy" from dual. To facilitate this in Java, we have to write String SQL ="select \"Dummy\" from dual"; This is what I explained. Basically, appropriate use of escape characters.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to comment on your answer, I tried to comment on the question.  I will delete my comment since it's not relevant to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a couple of '' characters, try the next:

```
SELECT      @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(RMSPROD2,''SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT   W.Bond) AS NoBID_Count
                                            FROM TIB.WRMAST w
                                            WHERE (w.BID In (''''No Bid'''', ''''No Cost'''', ''''None'''') AND w.CtlNumber = ''''' + @WarControlID + ''''''')'
```

Comment: I think you have way *too many* characters! You only need 2 apostrophes when escaping them, but you have 4 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an answer to this problem So I went with a different approach.  I used the OpenQuery with this code

```
SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(RMSPROD2,''SELECT TIB.WRMAST.WR_INVL, TIB.WRMAST.WR_WARR_CTL,TIBURON.WRMAST.WR_BAIL,TIB.WRWCHG.WC_BAIL
                       FROM TIB.WRMAST 
                       LEFT JOIN TIBURON.WRWCHG
                       ON WRWCHG.WC_WR_CHAIN = WRMAST.WRMAST_ROW
                       WHERE TIBURON.WRMAST.WR_WARR_CTL = ''''' + @WarControlID + ''''''')'
Insert Into @WarrantBail
   EXEC (@TSQL)
```

And placed the results into a Temp Table.  I was then able to use regular T-SQL to write the rest of the needed syntax.